# Feedback when text is copied to the clipboard

Tags: javascript

I have this React component that copies text to the clipboard.
How can I give feedback to the user when the text is copied to the clipboard?

```
export default function Share() {
  return (

      <button
        title="Share"
        type="button"
        onClick={() =>
          navigator.clipboard.writeText("Copy text")
        }
      > Share
      </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show alert

```
export default function Share() {
    return (
        <button
            title="Share"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
                navigator.clipboard.writeText('Copy text').then(() => {
                    alert('Text copied to clipboard');
                });
            }}
        >
            Share
        </button>
    );
}
```

Comment: the alert actually mess with copy in the clipboard

Comment: I just saw the writeText function return promise, edited the code to wait till it finishes before alerting.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the technical character of this question I would like to give a UX viewpoint on this. In my personal opinion Alerts are bad for nearly every user interaction since it is a disruptive message (user has to interact to proceed).

In this concrete example I would advice to rename the button instead of showing an alert as a simple non-disruptive user feedback. The great benefit is, that the users focus will be on the button when clicking it, so even small changes will be immediately recognized and contextually understood.

Alternatevely, if the button has to be reused and can't be renamed, you could look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify to show a toast that will not block following user interactions.